# Is the spaceship in Flight of the Navigator a robot?

Tags: time-travel, robots, flight-of-the-navigator

It's an old movie, sure, but I've been wondering if the ship is actually robotic or if it has an unseen pilot that speaks to David.

Comment: Good questions, but they should probably be split into separate posts.

Comment: Oh, you're not Rondo...

Comment: @DampeS8N [You sure about that?](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Josef+Divonne&oq=Josef+Divonne&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Mooz - Hehe. I spotted that.

Comment: Since this is an old question and since the only existing answer doesn't address the second question, I've edited it out. If the OP wants to re-ask the second question, they should do so.

Answer (score 13):

Great movie.  A favorite of mine when I was younger.  Yes, the ship is a completely robotic artificial intelligence.  The only other biological creatures on board the ship are the various animals the ship has collected from various other worlds as part of its mission of exploration.  The reason the ship didn't want to go back in time is that it feared that humans were not biologically strong enough to withstand the strains of time travel.  The ship only eventually agrees to take David back because he was so sad at being stranded 8 years out of time without his family.

Comment: +1 to you! That's exactly what I was going to say.

Answer (score 13):

This is addressed directly in the film.

> **David:** *Yeah, So what do I call you, anyway?*
>
> **Max:** ***I am a Trimaxion drone ship** from...*
>
> **David:** *Trimaxion?*
>
> <sub><sup>[Flight of the Navigator - Script](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:00j-SohHoIIJ:www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/f/flight-of-the-navigator-script.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)</sup></sub>

Since it's speaking directly to David, it's clear that it *is* the ship.